# jquery Autocomplete is not loading the results correctly and menu doesn't show unless I press down key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

This is what I have:

```
    searchTimeoutID;
    InitQuickSearch = function() {
        $( 'input#quick-search' ).autocomplete({
            source: []
        });

        $('input#quick-search', document).on('keyup', function(e) {
            switch(e.which) {
                default: // live search
                    window.clearTimeout(searchTimeoutID); // remove timer
                    var str = $(this).val(); // search string
                    if (str !== '') { // do the search
                        searchTimeoutID = window.setTimeout(LiveSearch, 100);
                    }
                break;
            }
        });
    };

    LiveSearch = function() {
        var str = $('input#quick-search').val();
        if(str !== '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/livesearch',
                data: { query: str },
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    var results = data.split(',');
                    alert(results); // displays correct results here

                    $( 'input#quick-search' ).autocomplete( 'option', { source: results });
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    printError(response);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    };
```

When I output the results variable using alert(results), the values look correct.

However, when I try and update the values in autocomplete it does not display the correct values. Also, I have to press the down key for the menu to appear.

$( 'input#quick-search' ).autocomplete( 'option', { source: results });

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change:

```
searchTimeoutID = window.setTimeout(LiveSearch, 100);
```

to:

```
LiveSearch();
```